# Is there a tool that can generate apache isis application?

Tags: isis

Is there a tool that can generate an apache isis application from JPA classes? Or do I have to rewrite everything with ISIS annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Currently [Apache Isis](http://isis.apache.org/) works with [JDO](http://db.apache.org/jdo/), not JPA, so your larger piece of work is to change the JPA annotations.  Under the covers we use [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/), which does support JPA, so alternatively you could provide a contribution to enable JPA (this is on our roadmap anyway).

There is no need to add any Isis annotations, but I do anticipate you would need to write additional code in order to expose the business functionality surrounding your core entities.  Isis' support for [contributed actions](http://isis.apache.org/more-advanced-topics/how-to-01-062-How-to-decouple-dependencies-using-contributions.html) and [subscribers](http://isis.apache.org/reference/services/event-bus-service.html) (over an in-memory event bus) would be a good way to do that.

For further questions, please subscribe to the [Isis users mailing list](http://isis.apache.org/support.html).

Comment: thank you for providing infos.. Yup, I have seen your posts in Youtube.. looks like being used along with DataNucleus..! the list of annotations really takes care of UI..!! Fantastic..! Can I customize it may be with an external HTML templates, or more specifically, my own directives or components..!?